# Artifact lost with retreating hero?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

There are many scenarios where you have to deliver a certain artifact to a Seer's Hut or equivalent to be able finish the game. Then an enemy player can find the artifact first and, while battling you, retreat (with the artifact). If you at first don't notice this and don't immediately buy the defeated hero from the tavern (when you already destroyed the enemy) is it possible to buy heroes from the tavern until the needed hero is purchasable again? Should you instead wait for weeks to pass and wait until the needed hero is available?

Ps. I tried this for a while as I realized what had happened, but gave up after buying about 50 heroes with no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If an enemy hero retreats from battle, he will immediately reappear for rehire in their taverns and will not be available to you for the remainder of the week. If the enemy cannot or does not rehire the hero, he returns to the normal hero pool at the beginning of the next week and may appear in your tavern, too.

If the player this hero belonged to can recruit heroes (depends on the scenario, but basically, if the AI-player has the gold and a town where he can recruit heroes in), they will nearly always be rehired by them and you can fight him again to get his artifacts.

A completely defeated hero can appear in the tavern again, but, in my experience, not in the same week he was defeated in.
In that case, exercise some patience and let time pass, eventually you can get the required hero unless he gets recruited by another player.

Answer (score -1):

A defeated hero can be hired in your tavern but it is random when he appears, so you will likely have to buy a few before he appears. Also do not dismiss the wrong heroes right away since returning them to the pool will give less chance for the one you want. Also you need to buy him right away to avoid enemy buying him back. So time is definitely against you.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. As you can see from the question, the enemy hero in question retreated from combat and I addressed that in the first part of my answer. Trying to hire him is impossible, as the hero is reserved for his previous owner until the next week. The second part addresses the unlikely cases that the enemy hero doesn't get rehired by its previous owner or gets defeated by neutrals and thus gets removed from play with all of his artifacts. If that happens and you are trying to maximize score, you are better off restarting the scenario cont...

Comment: ... cont. as chain hiring heroes hoping to get the one you need is not something your economy can handle when trying to play as fast as possible. For that matter, the game isn't about "completing as fast as possible". This just nets you the highest score. Some players enjoy it more to make their main hero as powerful as possible. Some players enjoy exploring the entire map. Some players enjoy building up every town.